Difficulty Retrieving JSON Data from API in Python
I'm attempting to retrieve JSON data from a server that provides information about a game. The website I'm interacting with is dofusdb.fr/fr/tools/treasure-hunt. Upon entering coordinates and clicking on one of the four directional arrows, the website sends four requests, with the response of the last one containing the data I'm interested in.
The first request involves sending data to Google with a cookie, which returns a token required for the last request. However, I'm encountering difficulties with the second request, which also involves Google, and I'm unsure how to proceed.
Here's an example of the second request I'm trying to understand:
POST /recaptcha/enterprise/clr?k=6Lfd6... HTTP/2
Host: www.google.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:125.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/125.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-CA,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Content-Type: application/x-protobuf
Content-Length: 1735
Origin: https://www.google.com
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/enterprise/anchor?...
Cookie: _GRECAPTCHA=09AKPP-6f4E9WP-7x3Rbln3-n7ZTF2OcVX5Jsfc6XHnBzLMSoYO4X0TO5m98oIWTOe5Phzt9QGeJ3EID9xpzsuAbc
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin

(i cut some long part)
Additionally, I'm having trouble retrieving data from the fourth request, which is made to the website's API and returns JSON data. Here's an example of the fourth request:
GET /treasure-hunt?x=1&y=2&direction=4&$limit=50&lang=fr HTTP/2
Host: api.dofusdb.fr
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:125.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/125.0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: en-CA,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
token: 03AFcWe...
Origin: https://dofusdb.fr
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: https://dofusdb.fr/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
If-None-Match: W/"137c-U9V1tcXlBJJw8dODoVz3KV3/Fig"
TE: trailers

i want to be able to retrieve the json data of the last one automatically with a python program.
I've attempted to retrieve the JSON data programmatically using the Python requests module, but all four requests returned empty responses. Additionally, I tried using a headless Selenium WebDriver with a proxy server, but encountered the same issue of empty data despite the website loading correctly.
I've heard about using httpx and hyper in Python for similar tasks, but I'm hesitant to downgrade my Python dependencies as it may affect other parts of my codebase.
Any advice or guidance or even other way on how to successfully retrieve the JSON data from the API using Python would be greatly appreciated.
code of my selenium might be some word in french:
# browser_actions.py

from browsermobproxy import Server
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from config import TEMPS_SCREENSHOT_PATH, PROXY_PATH
import shutil
import time
import os
import ssl
import json

def start_chrome_driver():
    # Create a SSL context that ignores certificate errors
    ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context()
    ssl_context.check_hostname = False
    ssl_context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

    # Start the BrowserMob Proxy server and create a proxy
    server = Server(PROXY_PATH)
    server.start()
    proxy = server.create_proxy()

    #Starts a headless Chrome browser.
    user_agent ="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0"
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server={proxy.proxy}')
    options.add_argument(f'--user-agent={user_agent}')
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')

    options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server={proxy.proxy}')

    driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)


    return driver, server, proxy

def navigate_to_page(driver, url):
    """Navigates to the specified URL."""
    driver.get(url)
    driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)

def enter_coordinates(driver, x, y):
    """Enters the coordinates (X, Y) into the input fields on the webpage."""
    input_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@placeholder="X"]')
    input_element.send_keys(x)
    input_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@placeholder="Y"]')
    input_element.send_keys(y)

def click_arrow_button(driver, way):
    """Clicks the arrow button on the webpage."""
    left_arrow_button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'fa-arrow-' + way)
    left_arrow_button.click()


def search_item(driver, search_query):
    try:
        """Enters a search query into the search bar and clicks the search button."""
        search_bar = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[type="search"]')
        ActionChains(driver).click(search_bar).perform()
        search_bar.send_keys(search_query)
        time.sleep(3)  # Give time for search results to load
        element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'//*[text()="{search_query}"]')
        element.click()
        element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        time.sleep(2)
        
    except:
        driver.save_screenshot(TEMPS_SCREENSHOT_PATH + "\\error.png")

def save_screenshot(driver):
    """Saves a screenshot of the webpage."""
    driver.save_screenshot(TEMPS_SCREENSHOT_PATH + "\\full_page_coords.png")

def delete_screen():
    shutil.rmtree(TEMPS_SCREENSHOT_PATH)
    os.mkdir(TEMPS_SCREENSHOT_PATH)

def suppress_exception_in_del(uc):
    old_del = uc.Chrome.__del__

    def new_del(self) -> None:
        try:
            old_del(self)
        except:
            pass
    
    setattr(uc.Chrome, '__del__', new_del)

def execute_chassebot(url, x, y, way, search_query):
    start_time = time.time()
    """Executes the chassebot actions in the desired order."""
    suppress_exception_in_del(uc)
    delete_screen()
    driver, server, proxy = start_chrome_driver()
    navigate_to_page(driver, url)
    enter_coordinates(driver, x, y)
    proxy.new_har("chassebot")
    click_arrow_button(driver, way)
    search_item(driver, search_query)
    time.sleep(2)
    save_screenshot(driver)
    har_data = proxy.har
    with open("chassebot.har", "w") as har_file:
        json.dump(har_data, har_file)
    driver.quit()
    server.stop()
    end_time = time.time()
    print(f"navigate_to_page took {end_time - start_time} seconds to run")
    time.sleep(1)

execute_chassebot("https://dofusdb.fr/fr/tools/treasure-hunt", 10, 5, "left", "")

and here is the screenshot at the end, we can see all the name in the dropdown.
full_page_coords.png

what did you try? Where is your code?

The second request is used to implement the CAPTCHA on the web site, which is for preventing automated use of the API. It has to be from a page that verifies a human is initiating the request.

maybe it uses some JavaScript code - so you may need to use Selenium  to control real web browser which can run JavaScript

i don't think the java script is the issue, after all the selenium processing, i take a screenshot and i can the the data that i am trying to take. I modified my question to give the code of my selenium and the screenshot of the driver

You're literally trying to defeat a CAPTCHA. It's possible, but doing so from scratch is fairly sophisticated . CAPTCHA's are designed to prevent people/bots from programmatically requesting web resources, as you are doing. Helping you defeat a CAPTCHA on StackOverflow is questionably unethical, so you may not receive much help here.

how can it know ? should i run it without the headless?

It knows because it's collecting information that the browser's DOM generates. Simply making a HTTP request avoids rendering the requested content, and therefore the browser never has a chance to dynamically generate the CAPTCHA payload and thus you don't pass the CAPTCHA check. Even if you run the code through an automation framework such as Selenium, part of the CAPTCHA payload includes signals for User Agent and other browser specific information intended to fingerprint the device and detect automation. In the end, you will have to spoof the CAPTCHA signals to defeat it.

but how can my proxy not get it ? we can see on the screenshot that the data went trough ?

Ironically, a proxy can make your requests look even more suspicious. You're up against Google ReCaptcha Enterprise. It works by collecting signals/fingerprints from the browser on an initial page load. If the signals look suspicious, it may issue a challenge (either interactive or silent) to determine if it thinks you're a human or not. Browser fingerprinting is highly sophisticated. Check out Creep JS to see the type of data it collects. It can be defeated but it takes research and it is considered unethical by many so it isn't appropriate for S.O.

ok thanks for the help look like i will do ocr !
